Return the percentage of the month that has elapsed up to today's date
I want a formula to return the percentage of the month that has elapsed up to today's date.
For example, if today is April 6, and April has 30 days, then the result would be 20%:
6 / 30 = 20%

What formula should I use to perform this calculation?

Use DAY w/ EOMONTH
NA Locale
=DAY(TODAY())/DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))

International
=DAY(TODAY())/DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY();0))

Format the cell's number format as percentage %

EOMONTH function
Returns a date representing the last day of a month which falls a specified number of months before or after another date.
NA Syntax
EOMONTH(start_date, months)

International
EOMONTH(start_date; months)

instead of "," gdocs accepted ";", but then it works! REALLY thanks!

You must be in a locale that uses , as decimal separator. Therefore in Sheets you use ; as argument separator and \  as column separator in arrays. Without including a formula or decimal number in your question there's no clue to  pick up on that. This site typically defaults to  North-American syntax for better or worse. In future you can note your locale in your questions or simply assume you will need to make those changes. I'll normally show both syntaxes if I know OP doesn't use NA syntax
